# Elrte and Elfinder setup on laravel

Tags: php, javascript, laravel, elrte, elfinder

I am using laravel on a Mcbook with mamp as the testing environment.

I have setup elrte and elfinder using this code:

```
var dialog;
    $('.elrte').elrte({
        toolbar      : 'maxi',
        fmOpen: function(callback) {
            if (!dialog) {
                // create new elFinder
                dialog = $('<div />').dialogelfinder({
                    url: '/mycms-laravel/elfinder/php/connector.php',
                    commandsOptions: {
                        getfile: {
                            oncomplete : 'close' // close/hide elFinder
                        }
                    },
                    getFileCallback: callback // pass callback to file manager
                });
            } else {
                // reopen elFinder
                dialog.dialogelfinder('open')
            }
        }
    });
```

But get this message:

Invalid backend configuration.
Readable volumes not available.

Have I not setup the config file?
What should it be for a laravel environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The connector.php file should be in the public folder. Can you access the file in your browser?
You can use chrome developer tools or firebug, to see how the script is called (in network/xhr-requests). Is the script found? Or turn on errors and see what errors the connector.php file produces.